# Connection Error Cannot connect to server: websocket error. Check if server is reachable at wss://creyente.vercel.app/_event

Tags: vscode

tengo este error al subir mi proyecto de github en vscode donde lo programe no me da ninugn error despues de subir a git hub y crear proyecto en vercel me sale este error

Connection Error
Cannot connect to server: websocket error. Check if server is reachable at wss://creyente.vercel.app/_event
y no entiendo por que

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, lecturas obligatorias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y revisando en la red, encontré esto que quizás te sea de utilidad: https://vercel.com/guides/publish-and-subscribe-to-realtime-data-on-vercel Saludos.